# Prove or disprove: If $A \subseteq B$ and $B$ is denumerable, then $A$ is denumerable

Tags: proof-writing, proof-verification

Claim: If $A \subseteq B$ and $B$ is denumerable, then $A$ is denumerable

Proof: Assume $A \subseteq B$ and $B$ is denumerable, then it follows that $B$ is countable. Every subset of a countable set is countable, so $A$ is countable (denumerable).

Is this proof valid? If $A$ is countable, then it could be either finite or denumerable, right? How can I prove that it's denumerable and not just finite?

Similarly, if $A \subseteq B$ and $A$ is denumerable, then $B$ is denumerable. I know that $A$ is countable, so $B$ is countable as well since $A$ is a subset of $B$. However, how can I show that $B$ is denumerable and not just finite?

Comment: For completeness: What is the definition of "countable" and "denumerable" that you are using?

Comment: I think when they say B is denumerable that includes the possibility that it may be finite.  Because it may well be.

Comment: @AldoGuzmánSáenz Set $S$ is denumerable if $S \approx \mathbb{N}$. A countable set is either finite or denumerable

Comment: Hmm... It appears that the first claim is false, then. Take, for instance, $A=\{1\}$, $B=\mathbb{N}$, we have $A\subseteq B$, $B$ is denumerable, but $A$ is not denumerable, using this definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first claim is indeed true. The key to the proof is to use the following (equivalent) definition of denumerability ( = **countably infinite** )
Def: a set $X$ is denumerable if all of its elements can be enumerated in a sequence, i.e.all of its elements can be listed as a sequence $x(1), x(2), ...x(n)$, ...
So using this definition we can write a proof for this claim.
Suppose $A$ is a subset of $B$ and $B$ is denumerable. So we can enumerate the elements of $B$ as a sequence $x(1), x(2), ..., x(n),.$. The subsequence consisting of those elements that belong to $A$ is then an enumeration of $A$. We are done.

The second claim is not true. Take $A = \mathbb{N}$ and $B = \mathbb{R}$, then $A$ is a subset of $B$ and $A$ is denumerable while $B$ is not.

Comment: In the first claim, $A$ could be finite and not denumerable.  Denumerable means countably infinite.